# Visual Studio 2013 App_Code / Web Config imported namespaces

Tags: visual-studio

I have upgraded a web project from visual studio 2008 to 2013 and I'm finding I'm having to manually include namespaces in app_code files.

In 2008 the imported namespaces in web config would helpfully apply to the files in the app_code folder.

Is this a generic thing for VS 2013 or am I having a brain failure?

I've searched the web but can't find the answer :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was brain failure after all.

My web config had the older version of crystal reports run time referenced and therefore couldn't build using the config file.